# Image compression before uploading in android

Tags: android, image, image-processing

I have a image uploading module in my app where user can select an image from the gallery. The problem is the size of the image can be upto 10MB. Which is very large, I want to apply some compression technique to these images before uploading them.

I did some research on the internet and found some libraries like ImageMagick, ImgMin which allows easy optimization of the images. Is there any way I can use them in my android project without the involvement of any backend server.

References:

ImgMin
https://github.com/rflynn/imgmin

ImageMagick
http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php﻿

Comment: Did you tried this way : convert your image to `Base64` format. Then you will get a String. If String is too big for example 20 mb split String to parts and upload them. If you want i can give you Base64 code.

Comment: I am already using S3 sdk to upload the images, it automatically manages the chunks. The problem is, images taken from a camera can go upto a large size and eventually contain lots of useless data which I don't want. ImgMin (as I mentioned above) uses the exact technique which I want to implement.

Answer (score 1):

An easy option you can try is [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress(android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream)) method from the `Bitmap` class.

You can select the compression format of a bitmap and to optimise either the quality, or the file size. A downside is that the you need to get a `Bitmap` instance to start the compression, which may be something you don't want to do.

Comment: Exactly! The bitmap conversion also causes significant loss in the image quality, which is not negotiable with the size compression it provides.

Comment: @SouravChandra you can use ImageMin for a standalone client and provide a JNI wrapper. It's not super simple to do, but I think it can be an option for you. Another thing is to try the Java interface of ImageMagick - there is a link in the page you posted.

Comment: Yes bro, I just discovered its a hell lot of work ahead to achieve this.